# How can I enable visual effects?

Tags: compiz, laptop, effects

I want to enable visual effects on my laptop with this specifications:
Ubuntu 11.10
Lenovo S100
CPU: Intel Atom CPU N570 @ 1.66 GHz x 4
Graphics: Unknown?
OS Type: 32 bit
Disk: 312.9 GB
How can I do that safely?

Comment: Are there any drivers shown in the additional drivers tool?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Unity 3D edition? If yes, you already got viusal effects activated (like a good looking alt-tab windows).
You can play with these effects by using CompizConfig SettingsManager (from Software Center). But be carefull. It's easy to break your settings and thus leaving you with a non working environment)

If you're usind Unity 2D edition you have to select the 3D edition on the login screen.

Good luck.